# Change CheckBox Style inside AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, selector, android-alertdialog

I am having troubles changing the chexbox theme of a Alert Dialog. I am not able to change selected checkbox color to my AccentColor.

this is my style code

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">      
<item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CustomCheckBox</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomCheckBox"     parent="android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
<item name="android:button">@drawable/activated_checkbox</item>
</style>
```

Selector : activated_checkbox

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- checked -->
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/AccentColor">
</item>
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/White">
</item>
</selector>
```

and method that shows the AlertDialog.

```
private void showDialog() {

    final CharSequence[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tipoDescargas);
    final boolean[] states = {false, false, false};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.preguntaDescargas));
    builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, states, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int item, boolean state) {
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Descargar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            SparseBooleanArray CheCked = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
            if (CheCked.get(0) && CheCked.get(1) && CheCked.get(2))
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "TODOS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (CheCked.get(0)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Item 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (CheCked.get(1)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Item 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (CheCked.get(2)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Item 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });builder.create().show();
}
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you

**UPDATE 1**

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:checkedTextViewStyle">@style/CustomCheckBox</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/activated_checkbox</item>
</style>
```

**SOLUTION**

I found the solution that display correctly the color.

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/activated_checkbox</item>
</style>
```

and Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkedcheckbox24"     android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheckedcheckbox24"     android:state_checked="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a working code snippet of JSFiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this code, icons displays correctly

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/activated_checkbox</item>
</style>
```

and the selector code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkedcheckbox24"     android:state_checked="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheckedcheckbox24"     android:state_checked="false"></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use custom selector for customizing your check box.

```
<CheckBox
    android:text="Custom CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Your Selector class , put it in drawable folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkedimage" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/uncheckedimage" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default multi choice layout that `AlertDialog` uses for presenting each option is in fact a [`CheckedTextView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckedTextView.html). Since this class doesn't extend `CheckBox` in any way, the `android:checkboxStyle` reference in your theme will have no effect.

API level 17 added the attribute [`android:checkedTextViewStyle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#checkedTextViewStyle), which can be used to style `CheckedTextView` specifically. If your minimum sdk version is set to this, or any higher version, then you could use this approach.

An alternative that, also available on older platforms, is [`android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listChoiceIndicatorMultiple) (there is also an equivalent for single choice items, or perhaps better said: items that visually look like radio buttons, but again, are `CheckedTextView` in reality). Use this to supply your own drawable that is to be displayed as checkmark (or radio button circle).

Comment: i am trying with this new code: UPDATE 1, but it doesn't work